# Unable to set data into database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

In this below code im trying get and set data from the data base but during execution im unable set data in the data base ...

### SettingUp

```
mWirelessRouters = WalletWirelessRouter.get(getActivity()).getWirelessRouter(uuid);
```

### onTextChanged Listner

```
 mBaseStationName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.base_station_name);
    mBaseStationName.setText(mWirelessRouters.getBaseStationName());
    mBaseStationName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged
                (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged
                (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           mWirelessRouters.setBaseStationName(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged
                (Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

**Note:-** In the above code im trying take the base station name from the user and update it in database..There is no issue related view

### getWirelessRouter(UUID uuid)

```
 public WirelessRouter getWirelessRouter(UUID id)
{
    WalletCursorWrapper cursor = queryWireless(
            WalletDbSchema.WirelessRouter.Cols.UUID + " =? "
            , new String[]
                    {
                            id.toString()
                    }
    );

    try {
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getWirelessRouter();
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

### queryWireless

```
 private WalletCursorWrapper queryWireless (String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
{
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
            WalletDbSchema.WirelessRouter.NAME,
            null, // Colums - null select all colums
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null, //groupBy
            null, //having
            null // order

    );

    return new WalletCursorWrapper(cursor);
}
```

### setBaseStation

```
 public void setBaseStationName(String baseStationName) {
    mBaseStationName = baseStationName;
}
```

### Insert()

```
public void addWireless (WirelessRouter w)
{
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(w);

    mDatabase.insert(WalletDbSchema.WirelessRouter.NAME, null, values);
}
```

### Starting new Fragment

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_item_new:
             WirelessRouter wirelessRouter = new WirelessRouter();
            WalletWirelessRouter.get(getActivity()).addWireless(wirelessRouter);
            Intent intent = WirelessRouterPagerActivity
                    .newIntent(getActivity(), wirelessRouter.getUUID());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Note:-I'm inserting Empty String data into database while creating the fragment

### Update Database

```
 public void upDateWireless(WirelessRouter wirelessRouter)
{
    String uuidString = wirelessRouter.getUUID().toString();
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(wirelessRouter);

    mDatabase.update(WalletDbSchema.WirelessRouter.NAME, values,
            WalletDbSchema.WirelessRouter.Cols.UUID + " =?"
            , new String[]{uuidString});
}
```

### Writable Datbase

```
 public WalletWirelessRouter (Context context)
{
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mDatabase = new WalletBaseHelper(mContext)
            .getWritableDatabase();
}
```

If you need any more data please let me know

Comment: where is code from `setBaseStationName()`?

Comment: @DavidM I have updated the code please check..

Comment: hmmm. where do you `insert()` it into the database?

Comment: i don't see where you call `mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();` prior to the `insert()`

Comment: @DavidM i have called it in my constructor...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in a transaction (and COMMIT it) if you want the values to be saved on completion.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction()
```

...insert, update, delete, etc

```
if (ok) {
   db.setTransactionSucessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

This *always* works for me.

Comment: I'm getting same out put no different from previous

Comment: after the `insert()` can you check if the number of records went up (by one) by running `DatabaseUtils.queryNumRecords(mDatabase, <tblName>, null, null);`? that way we know the record made it in or not...

Comment: All the values are getting into the database

Comment: so the problem is retrieving the data...the `insert()` is working? if you simplify your `where` statement, do you get the data?

Comment: in the `query()` in your function `queryWireless()`. with no whereClause and whereArgs...you should get data. if so, the problem is there.

Comment: With no where parameter I'll get into more trouble because I'll be populating this table with lot of data I want to differentiate it with uuid check the getWirelessRouter code above you will understand...

Comment: Yes! but we're trying to debug and find out where the error lies (first). i *think* the problem is in your `where` clause. we need to prove or disprove that assertion. you could just comment them out...as this is a temporary test. of course do as you see fit.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for late reply... I went to a movie... At last I found the solution I totally forgot to update the database in WirelessRouterFragment... I just had to override on pause and write code to upDateWireless... Anyway thanks for helping me...thank you David